# MySQLi query to get maximal id in the table?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","mydatabase");

 if ($result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id` FROM `mytable` WHERE `row1`=? OR `row2`=?"))
 {

    $id = 2;
    $result->bind_param("ii",$id,$id);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($max);
    $result->close();

    var_dump($max);

 }

 $mysqli->close();
```

Unfortunately this code always showing **NULL**, can u folk explain me how to reach a result?

**updated:**

in console mode staff like this works great. field `id` is int and incremental (as PRIMARY INDEX), other fields it's just a rows with a different int values, I cant change anything.

**updated:**

Well, seems I found the solution:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","mydatabase");

 if ($result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id` FROM `mytable` WHERE `row1`=? OR `row2`=?"))
 {

    $id = 2;
    $result->bind_param("ii",$id,$id);
    $result->execute();
    $obj = $result->get_result()->fetch_object();
    $max = $obj->id;
    $result->close();

    var_dump($max);

 }

 $mysqli->close();
```

this is it.

Comment: If you simply execute it from the console, do you get a result? `SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM mytable WHERE row1=2 OR row2=2`

Comment: if you want the column to grow automatically , why not created the column as identity column?

Comment: Beat me to it! Good job.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out this way:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `TableName` ORDER BY `PID` DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$pidmax=$row['PID'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You still need to call fetch, as max will only be available after that point. See doc: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

```
$result->bind_result($max);

/* fetch values */
while ($result->fetch()) {
    printf("Max ID %i\n", $max);
}

$result->close();
```